# Weird resize with background-size auto

Tags: html, css, background, autoresize, background-size

I want to add a background image on my body with the auto background-size.

The problem is my image is resized automatically.

My image's width is **2501px** and it is resized to a width of **640px**.

**Here is my resized background:**

[image: my resized background]

I saw an example of background with a background-size: auto with a **1440px** width image, and it is not resizing.

**The Example I saw:**

[image: example I saw]

**This is my CSS:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

body,html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

    background-color: #272727;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/t4JgQsP/Background-large.png");
    /* background-size: cover; */
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }

.test {
    width: 200px; /* Set a specific width for the element */
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.child.one {
    color:aquamarine;

}

#astro {
    padding-top: 8608px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    max-height: 67%;
    /* opacity: 40%; */
  
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px cyan);
    
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-name: respiration;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes respiration {
    from {
      filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px cyan);
    }
    
    50% {
      filter: drop-shadow(0 0 25px cyan);
    }
  
    to {
      filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px cyan);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; /* Center content vertically */
    background-color: #272727;
    color: #fff;
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/t4JgQsP/Background-large.png");
    background-size: auto; /* Maintain original size */
    background-position: center center; /* Center the background image */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.test {
    width: 200px; /* Set a specific width for the element */
    text-align: center;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.child.one {
    color: aquamarine;
}

#astro {
    padding-top: 860px; /* Adjust padding as needed */
    max-height: 67%;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px cyan);
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-name: respiration;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes respiration {
    from {
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px cyan);
    }
    50% {
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 25px cyan);
    }
    to {
        filter: drop-shadow(0 0 5px cyan);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding further details to your answer, as it stands it is not obvious what you have changed, what the cause of the issue was, or why the changes you made resolve the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).